# How to pass javascript variable value to shell script which generates the html/javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, shell, variables

Here it's what I'm doing. In a shell script, I generate html code (via `cat <<EOF >output.html .... EOF`). In the html section, I have javascript function. The javascript function need print a string in certain position (say position i)which changes according to the position order.

In my shell script, I have an array which has the string information (say `${array[i]}`).

Following is in shell script:

```
    IFS=',' read -a array <<< "$line";
```

The array information is verified by print out.

Following is in my javascript:

```
    padding += "<td>" + i + "<u>${array[i]}</u></td>";
```

The problem I have here is that the value of "i" in javascript did not get passed into the array --- looks like I always, but not very sure, get ${array[0]}.

What is the way to pass the value of "i" in javascript part to the array which defined in the shell script part?

To make it a bit clear:
Say the array is aa bb cc dd and the array is defined in shell script part. When i=2 I need print out cc in my javascript part. When and where i is defined? it's defined by my javascript part (not my shell script part).

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the shell array into a Javascript array:

```
echo 'var array = ['
i=0
while [ $i -lt $((${#array} - 1)) ]
do
    echo "'${array[$i]}',"
done
if [ ${#array} -gt 0 ]
then echo "'${array[$((${#array} - 1))]'"
fi
```

Then within the Javascript you can refer to `array[i]`.

Comment: didn't quite follow what you suggested. I need the value of "i" from javascript, not i=0 all the way to ${#array}.

Comment: I guess we misunderstood each other. say the array is aa bb cc dd and the array is defined in shell script part, when i=2 I need print out cc in my javascript part. When i is defined? it's defined by my javascript part (not my shell script part).